# How do I send a nested list/array through socket.emit()

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

The code is:

```
//i want to send this matrix across to server
  const [matrix, setMatrix] = useState([
    ['', '', ''],
    ['', '', ''],
    ['', '', ''],
  ]);


//fn handler whr matrix is sent to server through socket.emit
  const updateGameMatrix = (column, row, symbol) => {
    const newMatrix = [...matrix];

    if (newMatrix[row][column] === "" || newMatrix[row][column] === null) {
      newMatrix[row][column] = symbol;
      setMatrix(newMatrix);
    }

    console.log("matrix outside update_game: " , newMatrix)  //prints the array
    socket.emit("update_game", ( newMatrix ) => {
      console.log("update game matrix: ", newMatrix)  //does not print anyt?
      setPlayerTurn(false);
    });
  };
```

On the server side, I listen to "update_game" that was emitted:

```
  socket.on("update_game", (newMatrix) => {
    console.log("MATRIX FOR UPDATE_GAME: ", newMatrix)  //printed: MATRIX FOR UPDATE_GAME:  [Function (anonymous)] 
    setPlayerTurn(false)
  });
});
```

Why does the socket receive my matrix as an anonymous function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're not sending the matrix - you're using `.emit()` incorrectly to send data.  Using a callback function with `.emit()` is only for when you want confirmation from the other end, not for sending data.  This code will send the matrix data:

```
socket.emit("update_game", newMatrix);
```

And, this code in the client will receive it:

```
socket.on("update_game", (newMatrix) => {
  console.log("MATRIX FOR UPDATE_GAME: ", newMatrix); 
});
```

Comment: Hi, oh i see! but what if i want to add the ```setPlayerTurn(false)``` inside the callback function for ```socket.on()```?

Comment: @newtocodingyikes - You can put `setPlayerTurn(false)` wherever you need it.  For example, you can put it on the line of code right after `socket.emit("update_game", newMatrix);`.  If you want to engage in callback confirmation of client receipt, that's an extra layer of callbacks and client response, but doesn't seem necessary here as it just creates extra network traffic and CPU usage and it doesn't appear necessary.